# Is there an easy way to extract partial css in element of html?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, browser, frontend

Many elements refer to many css and many css refer to many elements.

Is there a technique that is easiest to look at for an element of css?

For example:

I have a 1000 line html file and

I have a 1000 line css file

example i would like to know `<div class = 'container'>` and the inner element in line 574. Which css line is used?

Is there a method or tools that makes it easier or faster?

Comment: Most browsers have developers tool to inspect an element. In chrome you can access it with F12. Once the developer tools is open, click on the square with a cursor inside of it and then select the element you want to inspect the CSS for. In the right panel of the Developer tools, for each CSS property assigned to the selected element, will be a link to the stylesheet that the CSS property comes from. Click on that link and it will take you to the line of the CSS where that property resides.

Comment: how i can to  export reference css to css file?

Comment: Sorry, I only know how to manually check. What exactly are you trying to achieve and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easy way is to inspect element in your browser (key f12) and copy the css generated there. or you cand see the hole css file and extract what you want.